jMeter - How to escape quotes?
I need help to escape quotes in jMeter!
I've to put into a var some words with quotes, for example "dummy", so I've tried with:
vars.put("example", '"dummy"')
vars.put("example", "\"dummy\"")
vars.put("example", "&quotdummy&quot")

in order to create a variable called example with a value "dummy", but nothing of those attempts are working.
Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Your first 2 options are fine, you can see it yourself if you use different variable names and add a Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener after your JSR223 Test Element:

More information: Groovy - Strings
